# Encoded Table from all combinations of a list

Tags: python, pandas, iterable

I've spent a little while on this and got an answer but seems a little convoluted so curious if people have a better solution.

Given a list I want a table indicating all the possible combinations between the elements.

```
sample_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

(pd.concat(
    [
     pd.DataFrame(
         [dict.fromkeys(i, 1) for i in combinations(sample_list, j)]
         ) for j in range(len(sample_list)+1)
     ]).
    fillna(0).
    reset_index(drop = True)
    )
```

With the result, as desired:

```
      a    b    c    d
0   0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
1   1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
2   0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0
3   0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0
4   0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0
5   1.0  1.0  0.0  0.0
6   1.0  0.0  1.0  0.0
7   1.0  0.0  0.0  1.0
8   0.0  1.0  1.0  0.0
9   0.0  1.0  0.0  1.0
10  0.0  0.0  1.0  1.0
11  1.0  1.0  1.0  0.0
12  1.0  1.0  0.0  1.0
13  1.0  0.0  1.0  1.0
14  0.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
15  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
```

For learning purposes would like to know better solutions.

Thanks

Comment: This seems like a perfectly reasonable way to solve the problem, can you explain what would be a "better" way in your opinion? Less memory usage, less time to run, not using itertools, readability?

Comment: It just felt like a lot steps making nested list comprehension and swapping between lists, dictionaries and dataframes. 

The proposed solution below looks good

Comment: It's a perfectly reasonable question, but remember that stackoverflow exists as a site for specific questions and objective answers, so defining a success criteria more specific than "would like to know better solutions" can prevent it from being closed as "opinion-based". This also would be a good post for the [codereview.se] stack site given you have a solution but you want improvements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check Below code

```
import itertools
import pandas as pd

sample_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

pd.DataFrame(list(itertools.product([0, 1], repeat=len(sample_list))), columns=sample_list)
```

Output:

[image]